Django SSL Redirect causing local development connection issues in Chrome
After setting SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=True in my settings.py but False in my environment variables for local development and restarting the server and browser I cannot connect to my website via local host and get the
 You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
[21/Nov/2024 11:28:50] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01ü\x03\x03èª\x19óÆð?ë-\x99âÆH\x13V\x08{zm')

error. It works when I open it incognito and in other browsers but not in the current browser(Chrome).
Here is my settings.py:
SECRET_KEY = env.str("SECRET_KEY")
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = env.bool("DJANGO_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT", default=True)

SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = env.int("DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS", default=2592000)
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = env.bool("DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS", default=True)
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = env.bool("DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD", default=True)

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = env.bool("DJANGO_SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE", default=True)
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = env.bool("DJANGO_CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE", default=True)

Environment variables:
 DEBUG=True
SECRET_KEY=bTU5cQLjBGapg3d......mrVglq1CEhbk
DJANGO_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False

DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS=0
DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS=False
DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD=False

DJANGO_SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False
DJANGO_CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=False

I've deleted cookies for both localhost and 127.0.0.1, restarter Chrome and still had the same error in the end.
I'm sure django can see my .env file varibles as when I run --deploy I get the full deployment checklist:
WARNINGS:
?: (security.W004) You have not set a value for the SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS setting. If your entire site is served only over SSL, you may want to consider setting a value and enabling HTTP Strict Transport Security. Be sure to read the documentation first; enabling HSTS carelessly can cause serious, irreversible problems.
?: (security.W008) Your SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT setting is not set to True. Unless your site should be available over both SSL and non-SSL connections, you may want to either set this setting True or configure a load balancer or reverse-proxy server to redirect all connections to HTTPS.
?: (security.W012) SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE is not set to True. Using a secure-only session cookie makes it more difficult for network traffic sniffers to hijack user sessions.
?: (security.W016) You have 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in your MIDDLEWARE, but you have not set CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE to True. Using a secure-only CSRF cookie makes it more difficult for network traffic sniffers to steal the CSRF token.
?: (security.W018) You should not have DEBUG set to True in deployment.



are you sure you're reading your env variables?

@LordMooCow Yes. When I run --deploy I get the full deployment checklist. I added it to the post.
